# Rails syntax error assigning a variable with each loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to create a list of recipients to send in an external request by assigning it to a variable by doing the following:

```
recipients = @items.each do |item|
  {"email"=>"#{Recipient.find_by_id(item.recip_id).email}", "amount"=>"#{item.price}"},
end
```

but I'm getting this error:

```
syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting '}'
```

I know that what I've done is not the right syntax. I'm kind of a Ruby newbie, so can someone help me figure out the correct syntax here?

EDIT: Thanks for the input. But what if I need to do two hashes for each item?

```
recipients = @items.map do |item|
  {"email"=>"#{Recipient.find_by_id(item.recip_id).email}", "amount"=>"#{item.price}"},
  {"email"=>"#{Store.find_by_id(item.recip_id).email}", "amount"=>"#{item.price}"}
end
```

Comment: try removing the , at the end of the hash declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return multiple hashes from your `map` block then you'd be better off switching to [`each_with_object`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object):

> Iterates the given block for each element with an arbitrary object given, and returns the initially given object.

So something like this:

```
recipients = @items.each_with_object([]) do |item, a|
  a << {"email"=>"#{Recipient.find_by_id(item.recip_id).email}", "amount"=>"#{item.price}"}
  a << {"email"=>"#{Store.find_by_id(item.recip_id).email}", "amount"=>"#{item.price}"}
end
```

Comment: Ah! This finally solves it. I assume the << operator appends the hash to a?

Comment: @varatis: Yes, [`Array#<<`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-3C-3C) is the same as [`Array#push`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-push).

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with the comma at the end of the hash. Also if you want to store the email and amount in recipients, you should use map. This will return an array of hash with email and amount:

```
recipients = @items.map do |item|
  {"email"=> Recipient.find_by_id(item.recip_id).email, "amount"=> item.price}
end
```

Also, as you might note, I don't need to pass the values of email and prices as a string.

Comment: Ok thanks. But what if I need to do two hashes for each item (i.e. two email - amount pairs)? I've put an example in the question. Sorry - I realize I hadn't asked this before, but I recently realized I need two hashes for each item.

Comment: @varatis: You could return a two element array from your `map` block and then `flatten` the result or switch to `each_with_object([])` and push your two entries onto the array inside the block.

Comment: The problem with using hash is that they will need a unique key. So the key email can have only one value key. One way would be to use an hash of hash. Something like {"1" => {"email" => "abc", "amount" => "xyz"}, "2" => {"email" => "pqr", "amount" => "lmn"}}, where 1 and 2 can be the id's of items.

Comment: @WahajAli So there is no way to just make a simple array of hashes like [{"email" => email1, "amount"=> item1}, {"email" => email2, "amount" => item2}, ....]? I don't know why you'd need to make each entry have different keys.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I seem to have misunderstood your comment. I meant you could not have multiple keys with the same name in a single hash. What you wrote would work perfectly.

Comment: @WahajAli No problem. +1, thanks for your help -- sorry I changed my question halfway through.